# error while running hive mapreduce job

Tags: mapreduce, hive, kill

when I trying to run hive commands which involve mapreduce, I am getting the following error, please help me solve this:

```
hive (hiveclass)> create table companies2 as select * from companies;
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = hduser_20161105115631_5868a474-de3c-4cc9-80f9-40a6fac60fa2
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1478325284966_0010, Tracking URL = http://ubuntu:8088/proxy/application_1478325284966_0010/
Kill Command = /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1478325284966_0010
```

after kill command, nothing is happening. then I have to give ctrl+c and exit the hive shell.

Comment: It's not an error. It's a warning. Did you check it the table us available?

Comment: Table is available and while i am running hive commands with INSERT, ORDER BY or any commands which includes mapreduce processes then hive process is hanged after kill command and is not running further.

Comment: Did you check the jobs logs?  Inside them there is the real reason of the failure

Comment: 2016-11-06T00:09:36,356 INFO  [main]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:getLogIdVar(3511)) - Using the default value passed in for log id: 1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73
2016-11-06T00:09:36,461 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:updateThreadName(401))

Comment: - Updating thread name to 1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73 main
2016-11-06T00:09:36,462 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (:()) - Compiling command(queryId=hduser_20161106000936_43fc33d0-2d1c-48f3-91fd-15eb6febb98d): hive.querylog.location

Comment: 2016-11-06T00:09:36,483 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (:()) - FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hive' '.' 'querylog'
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hive' '.' 'querylog'
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:207)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:404)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:329)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:115

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1253)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1084)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1072)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: 2016-11-06T00:09:36,484 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (:()) - Completed compiling command(queryId=hduser_20161106000936_43fc33d0-2d1c-48f3-91fd-15eb6febb98d); Time taken: 0.022 seconds
2016-11-06T00:09:36,484 INFO  [1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73 main]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:getLogIdVar(3511)) - Using the default value passed in for log id: 1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73
2016-11-06T00:09:36,485 INFO  [1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73 main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:resetThreadName(412)) - Resetting thread name to  main

Comment: 2016-11-06T00:09:49,600 INFO  [main]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:getLogIdVar(3511)) - Using the default value passed in for log id: 1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73
2016-11-06T00:09:49,600 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:updateThreadName(401)) - Updating thread name to 1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73 main
2016-11-06T00:09:49,602 INFO  [1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73 main]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:getLogIdVar(3511)) - Using the default value passed in for log id: 1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73
2016-11-06T00:09:49,603 INFO  [1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c

Comment: 92c2-179892957b73
2016-11-06T00:09:49,600 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:updateThreadName(401)) - Updating thread name to 1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73 main
2016-11-06T00:09:49,602 INFO  [1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73 main]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:getLogIdVar(3511)) - Using the default value passed in for log id: 1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73
2016-11-06T00:09:49,603 INFO  [1e8c2a94-660b-4b6c-92c2-179892957b73 main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:resetThreadName(412)) - Resetting thread name to  main

Comment: This is my log file. please help me figure out the problem.

Comment: There is this error in your logs: ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (:()) - FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hive' '.' 'querylog'.  We should to start undestanding this point first.

Comment: As i am new to MapReduce and hive and never worked as a software developer, I dont know how to resolve this error. Help me with this..

Comment: Check if are not using any reserved keyword into your query / table definition. If you are, then use ` to escape them: I.E `date`

Comment: I am not using any reserved words and the problem is normal queries are working but queries with mapreduce job triggered are hanging out after kill command.

Comment: I refreshed my hive.log and i am sure there are no errors in it. its showing only INFO information init. I think the problem is with my MapReduce.Here are the processes running.

Comment: hduser@ubuntu:~$ jps
3636 ResourceManager
2965 NameNode
3430 SecondaryNameNode
8681 RunJar
8538 RunJar
9051 Jps
6939 DataNode
8268 RunJar
7583 RunJar

Comment: hduser@ubuntu:~$ jps -l
3636 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager
2965 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
3430 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode
8681 org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
8538 org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
6939 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode
8268 org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
10047 sun.tools.jps.Jps
7583 org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar